# Ant-contrib : AntCallback always returns same value

Tags: ant, echo, ant-contrib, antcall

My problem is;
When I call an antcallback function more than one, It returns the same value always. Check out the following code :

```
<project name="AntCallBack" default="testFnc" basedir=".">
   <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties" />

   <target name="acbFnc" description="Sub Function" >
      <echo message="[acbFnc] started"/>
      <property name="out.file" value="${in.file}"/>
      <echo message="[acbFnc] ended."/>
   </target>

   <target name="testFnc" description="Main" >

        <antcallback target="acbFnc" return="out.file" >
            <param name="in.file" value="TEST-1" />
        </antcallback>
        <echo message="CALL - 1 : out.file : ${out.file}" />

        <antcallback target="acbFnc" return="out.file" >
            <param name="in.file" value="TEST-2" />
        </antcallback>
        <echo message="CALL - 2 : out.file : ${out.file}" />

    </target>
</project>
```

The result is :

```
$ /home/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin/ant -f AntCallBackTest.xml
Buildfile: AntCallBackTest.xml

testFnc:

acbFnc:
     [echo] [acbFnc] started
     [echo] [acbFnc] ended.
     [echo] CALL - 1 : out.file : TEST-1

acbFnc:
     [echo] [acbFnc] started
     [echo] [acbFnc] ended.
     [echo] CALL - 2 : out.file : TEST-1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

As you see I sent "param name="in.file" value="TEST-1" " in first call,
And I sent "param name="in.file" value="TEST-2" " in second call,
But It always returned the first value :
[echo] CALL - 1 : out.file : TEST-1
[echo] CALL - 2 : out.file : TEST-1

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You're using ant like a scripting language, which it isn't.  Ant doesn't have variables or functions.  You're going to have a better time if you change build tools or let ant be ant and replace your target that you're using like a function with a [macro](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html)

Comment: @thekbb thx for answer. I will consider the design with using macro. I am newbie in Ant.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution :
I have to unset the variable before second call with :

```
<var name="out.file" unset="true"/>
```

I mean, it should be like this :

```
<target name="testFnc" description="Main" >

    <antcallback target="acbFnc" return="out.file" >
        <param name="in.file" value="TEST-1" />
    </antcallback>
    <echo message="CALL - 1 : out.file : ${out.file}" />

    <var name="out.file" unset="true"/>

    <antcallback target="acbFnc" return="out.file" >
        <param name="in.file" value="TEST-2" />
    </antcallback>
    <echo message="CALL - 2 : out.file : ${out.file}" />

</target>
```